# Styles to Hide Content when JS is Disabled

Tags: javascript, css, noscript

I have a site that has a buttons visible typically. If javascript is disabled then I want to hide that button from the user. I tried using the following code:

```
<noscript>
 <style>
   .cart-opt{display:none;}
 </style>
  <br>
 <div class="panel callout radius"> <h5>Please Enable Javascript</h5></div>
</noscript>
<div class="cart-opt opt-btns"> <!-- BUTTONS HERE SHOULD BE SHOWN WITH JS ENABLED--> </div>
```

This didn't work. Even though the `<style>` tag was wrapped in `<noscript>` tag it was still read and hid the buttons even when JS enabled.

How do I write the styles so the `<style>` tag isn't read unless JS is disabled?

Note: I am using HTML 5.

Comment: You can wrap the button with <noscript> instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this be an alternative solution?

```
<noscript>
 <div class="panel callout radius"> <h5>Please Enable Javascript</h5></div>
 <div style="display:none">
</noscript>

<div class="cart-opt opt-btns"> <!-- BUTTONS HERE --> </div>

<noscript>
  </div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Interesting option. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the button with `<noscript>` instead or you can hide the button initially (with CSS), and then display it with JavaScript.
In this case without the JavaScript, the button won't be shown

Also, leave the header notification (the one prompting user to use JS) inside the `<noscript>`.

Answer (score 0):

Make them initially hidden by class.

```
<style>.jscriptenabled{display:none;}</style>
```

Then if JavaScript is allowed, they will become visible!

```
<script>
document.write('<style> .jscriptenabled{display:inherit;} </style>');
</script>`
```